# Docker containers can't connect to mysql container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

so I'm new to docker and now I'm trying to connect my php, and adminer service to mysql service. Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 80:80

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    ports:
      - 3360:3306

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

After I ran the docker-compose up -d command, I opened adminer (localhost:8080) and fill the server field with 'db', username with 'test', password with 'test', database with 'test'. Then I clicked login but I got Connection timed out message, I can't login to the mysql service. The mysql service logs showed that the 'mysqld: ready for connections' already. Any ideas where I did it wrong? thank you :)

Comment: Default port (3306)?  Note that `networks: [default]` is the Compose default and you can delete those blocks, and that `links:` are obsolete and can also be deleted.

Comment: okay, at first I put neither of it in my docker-compose file but it didn't work. Then I put it, still nothing changed. But I've deleted it now. @DavidMaze

Comment: Your docker-compose works correctly with adminer/mysql. Sure no typo in password? Try it also with root root.

Comment: Is the port `3360:3306` a typo?

Comment: no, I need to access the mysql database to import the data dump from outside the container @super

Comment: I've tried both of the credentials. Root and test, neither of them works. @Ralle

Comment: Delete your ./mysql folder and retry.